# Stop column names from being altered in SSRS Report Builder 15.0

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, report-builder

I'm encountering an issue where Report Builder is arbitrarily removing characters from field names, and also adding spaces in front of capital letters in others. See image for example: two of them had underscores converted to spaces and others put spaces in front of the capital letters.

Is there any way to turn this functionality off? I am working on moving several reports to SSRS, and one of the early ones I'm working on has nearly 200 fields so I'm hoping I won't have to manually change field names in *all* of the reports I'm working on! Any guidance would be appreciated.

[image]